# Oracle CASE expression in query plan

Tags: oracle, vpd

The background to this question is that I am currently investigating the query plans generated by having Oracle VPD column masking policies active. I would assume that the underlying rewrite is expressed as a CASE expression, e.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN ss_quantity > 13 THEN ss_quantity ELSE NULL END ss_quantity FROM store_sales` to represent the cell-level policy `ss_quantity > 13` on the ss_quantity column of the store_sales table.

The goal is to be able to see and verify where in the query execution plan the CASE expression is executed. For instance in a query such as:

```
select ss_quantity
from store_sales, date_dim
where ss_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk
and d_year = 1998;
```

However, the execution plan generated from DBMS_XPLAN does not tell me where the CASE expression is executed. The plan is below. From this plan I cannot tell if the CASE statement is executed as part of the projection of the HASH JOIN (1) or as part of the projection of the TABLE ACCESS FULL (3).

Does anyone know a way to get this information?

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 2770377741
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |   117K|  5966K| 11576   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |             |   117K|  5966K| 11576   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DATE_DIM    |    15 |   390 |   377   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| STORE_SALES |  3035K|    75M| 11191   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - SEL$F5BB74E1
   2 - SEL$F5BB74E1 / "DATE_DIM"@"SEL$1"
   3 - SEL$F5BB74E1 / "STORE_SALES"@"SEL$2"
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("SS_SOLD_DATE_SK"="D_DATE_SK")
   2 - filter("D_YEAR"=1998)
 
Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - (#keys=1; rowset=256) "SS_QUANTITY"[NUMBER,22]
   2 - (rowset=256) "D_DATE_SK"[NUMBER,22]
   3 - (rowset=256) "SS_SOLD_DATE_SK"[NUMBER,22], "SS_QUANTITY"[NUMBER,22]
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Comment: "I would assume that the underlying rewrite is expressed as a CASE expression". I'm not sure that's a correct assumption, and Oracle typically doesn't break out column-level functions in an explain plan, unless they involve a separate sub-query.

Comment: @pmdba OK. Firstly, let’s suppose that I then add a CASE expression directly to the query in the manner that I have described without using VPD policies. I experience the same behaviour of the plan not showing where the logic happens. Secondly, if it doesn’t break out the functions like you have suggested, can I see them by some other means?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that granular in Oracle's optimizer reporting. You might see a difference in the overall cost of the query or its CPU usage, but you'd have to compare the actual query (i.e. *with* CASE) to a baseline version (*without CASE*) to see if there is any difference, and then you'd only be able to *guess* at the cause. With VPD, Oracle is rewriting the query on its own terms: you might be able to get the actual query text out of an AWR report and run an explain plan against *that*, but there's little if anything you can do about how Oracle chooses to execute the rewrite.

Comment: Most of the steps in an explain plan are about setting up the result set to which the query will be applied: I/O, joins, application of filter predicates, sorts, grouping, etc. Column level functions like `CASE` applied to the result set (i.e. not as "where" clause predicates) are rolled up in the `SELECT STATEMENT` step.